# R - lrm (logistic regression - rms package) - plot quarterly predicted and realised values

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression using the lrm package from rms.

```
mod1b <- lrm(dependent_variable ~ InterestRate + quarterYear, data = my_data)
print(mod1b)
```

and I get the following output:

```
> mod1b <- lrm(dependent_variable ~ InterestRate + quarterYear, data = my_data)
> print(mod1b)
Logistic Regression Model

 lrm(formula = dependent_variable ~ InterestRate + quarterYear, 
     data = my_data)

                       Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                          Ratio Test           Indexes           Indexes       
 Obs         19209    LR chi2    2976.40    R2       0.229    C       0.764    
  0          15465    d.f.            39    g        1.027    Dxy     0.528    
  1           3744    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       2.792    gamma   0.528    
 max |deriv| 7e-10                          gp       0.161    tau-a   0.166    
                                            Brier    0.130                     

                    Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
 Intercept          -1.1097 0.1956  -5.67 <0.0001 
 InterestRate       -5.9861 0.4951 -12.09 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=1 2010  1.8184 0.2197   8.28 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=1 2011  1.9568 0.2262   8.65 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=1 2012  0.9345 0.2321   4.03 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=1 2013 -0.3628 0.2544  -1.43 0.1537  
 quarterYear=1 2014 -0.2646 0.2250  -1.18 0.2396  
 quarterYear=1 2015 -0.2819 0.2228  -1.27 0.2057  
 quarterYear=1 2016 -0.3884 0.2233  -1.74 0.0820  
 quarterYear=1 2017 -0.8144 0.2308  -3.53 0.0004  
 quarterYear=2 2008  0.1082 0.2515   0.43 0.6670  
 quarterYear=2 2009 -0.0525 0.2673  -0.20 0.8444  
 quarterYear=2 2010  1.8369 0.2186   8.40 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=2 2011  1.8234 0.2207   8.26 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=2 2012  0.8353 0.2305   3.62 0.0003  
 quarterYear=2 2013 -0.3520 0.2532  -1.39 0.1645  
 quarterYear=2 2014 -0.1610 0.2242  -0.72 0.4726  
 quarterYear=2 2015 -0.6490 0.2304  -2.82 0.0048  
 quarterYear=2 2016 -0.5415 0.2258  -2.40 0.0165  
 quarterYear=2 2017 -1.0205 0.2395  -4.26 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=3 2008  0.0669 0.2479   0.27 0.7873  
 quarterYear=3 2009 -0.2095 0.2756  -0.76 0.4471  
 quarterYear=3 2010  1.6706 0.2198   7.60 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=3 2011  1.7254 0.2180   7.91 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=3 2012  0.6138 0.2380   2.58 0.0099  
 quarterYear=3 2013 -0.1977 0.2432  -0.81 0.4164  
 quarterYear=3 2014 -0.2383 0.2251  -1.06 0.2898  
 quarterYear=3 2015 -0.5890 0.2283  -2.58 0.0099  
 quarterYear=3 2016 -1.1334 0.2453  -4.62 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=3 2017 -0.7910 0.2309  -3.43 0.0006  
 quarterYear=4 2008  0.2528 0.2338   1.08 0.2796  
 quarterYear=4 2009 -0.1349 0.2744  -0.49 0.6229  
 quarterYear=4 2010  1.7066 0.2158   7.91 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=4 2011  1.7735 0.2223   7.98 <0.0001 
 quarterYear=4 2012  0.3225 0.2504   1.29 0.1977  
 quarterYear=4 2013  0.1738 0.2196   0.79 0.4288  
 quarterYear=4 2014 -0.4699 0.2306  -2.04 0.0416  
 quarterYear=4 2015 -0.4956 0.2252  -2.20 0.0277  
 quarterYear=4 2016 -0.8298 0.2335  -3.55 0.0004  
 quarterYear=4 2017 -0.7182 0.2363  -3.04 0.0024
```

How can I plot the predicted and realised percentages of zeros or ones in my data per quarter?

Comment: This question suggests a lack of knowledge of the definition of odds and odds ratios. Neither of those are percentages. Furthermore it is unclear what is desired. What tabulation is needed and what predictions are desired? Is this homework? If so, describe the data more fully and show more of your work so people can see where you are stuck.

Comment: I would like to plot per quarter the percentages of the variables that "move" from the value 0 to the value 1. I would like to plot the realised outcomes vs the ones that the model predicts.

Comment: Output suggests yearly data. Need better understanding of what is in data and why only yearly coefficients are seen.

Comment: The data is quarterly. What you see in the output as "1 2010" means this data point corresponds to the first quarter of 2010.

Comment: Then where are the other quarter coefficients?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: I think modeling such data with no consideration of trends and auto-correlation is not likely to give useful material for discussions. Segmenting the data into completely independent periods makes highly unlikely assumptions.

Comment: @42 What do you suggest that I do then?

Answer (score 0):

`polr` from the `MASS` package is the same proportional odds model and has a better defined `predict` method for the default S3 class. If one specifies `predict(<mypolrobj>, type='probs')` you get the response-level specific probabilities.